# Sprockets::FileNotFound while attempting to include external JS file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I am trying to get `rangeslider.js` working in `Ruby on Rails`. I have used their GitHub page as a reference, but couldn't find any help for Rails.

http://andreruffert.github.io/rangeslider.js/

**Application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require rangeslider.js
//= require rangeslider.min.js
//= require_tree .
```

I came across the following error message

```
 Sprockets::FileNotFound
(in C:/Users/rmatthews/Documents/repos/pcbuilder/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:17)
```

Line 17, was `//= require rangeslider.min.js`

The files are located on my computer, but in my `/downloads/rangeslider.js-0.3.7` directory

My guess is that Rails does not search that directory.

Do I need to place them somewhere else, like `/vendor/assets`?

I've been following this as a Reference, but couldn't find much

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline

I've seen a couple of similar questions, but since they were discussing `jquery`, they didn't seem to be of much help.

Answer (score 1):

Rails does not search random directories that exist outside of your application. You will need to place this file at `vendor/assets/rangeslider.js`.

Then require it by:

```
//= require rangeslider
```